# To check the similarity of distribution of categorical variables in Treatment and Control group

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, chi-squared-test, experiment-design

I have a dataset with 19variables. The dataset has a column as GROUP and it has 2 values- Treatment and Control. There is a column as CONVERTED which has value 'Yes' 'No'. Basically, I want to determine if a particular campaign was effective in terms of conversion or not. I did a Chi square test of independence by building a contingency table between these columns to determine the Chi square value and p- value. Then I also used cramersV to determine the strength of the relationship.
I am able to do this. But the question is now about the distribution of other attributes of customers in the 2 groups.

A customers has various attributes(I have these columns in the data) like Region, Affluent, OnlinePresence etc. Most of these attributes are multilevel categorical values. To do experimental analysis our Control and Treatment group should be as similar as possible. I have done random selection. But I want to know the distribution of other attributes as well in the 2 groups. I want to be sure that the distribution of suppose Affluent attribute is similar in both Control and Treatment group. Is there a way to determine the similarity of distribution of attributes in the 2 groups? Or would anyone have any idea how to proceed further?

I came across a concept called covariate shifts but I am not sure if that's right in this case?

Thanks.

Comment: A [two-sample chi-squared goodness of fit test](https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/software/dataplot/refman1/auxillar/chi2samp.htm) may be relevant for your use case. Though it is unclear to me if you are looking for a similarity measure between two categorical distributions, or a statistical test to see whether there is evidence for the distribution across categories in a sample (control) to be similar/different to that in the other sample (treatment). Please can you clarify?

Comment: Hi @B.Liu, I am actually looking for both. Could you please elaborate on this?